# invalid use of void expression when passing a function as parameter

Tags: c

I have a function called

```
GLOBAL char* GET_Enum(REC_NO  recNo )
{
  .....
}
```

also I have a function which take this function as an input like this

```
static void Dropdowns( char* param , 
                       char* title, 
                       char* (*enumFunction)(REC_NO),
                       int maxRecNo)
{
 .....
}
```

Then I call that function like this

```
Dropdowns("test", "Location", GET_Enum, 3);
```

But it doesn't compile and gives me the error below:

```
 error: invalid use of void expression
```

I have looked at this issues [Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9410/how-do-you-pass-a-function-as-a-parameter-in-c) and [Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22732007/error-invalid-use-of-void-expression) which are relevant but I still can't see what I am doing wrong? any idea? Thanks

Comment: give minimal, COMPLETE and verifiable code

Comment: @JacekCz it is a framework that I am using so it doesn't make much sense if I give the full code. but I update it a bit to make more sense.

Comment: at first: what is GLOBAL, REC_NO. Sample cannot be compiled without

Comment: thanks @JacekCz just change the Global to static, REC_NO is char[14]

Comment: The code you posted is fine.  The error about the void expression is coming from something else, that you haven't showed us.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems You have error in other place, or give us wrong additional information.

Code (with explanation) compile very well, MSVC 2015

```
#include "stdafx.h"

static char* GET_Enum(char  recNo[14] )
{
    return NULL;
}

static void Dropdowns(char* param,
    char* title,
    char* (*enumFunction)(char[14]),
    int maxRecNo)
{
}
int main()
{
    Dropdowns("test", "Location", GET_Enum, 3);
    return 0;
}
```

========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

Comment: ah I see thanks @Jacek